# How to check if at least a key exist in a dictionary based on a list of string?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings:

```
fields = ["website", "product_url", "catalog_url", "dop_url", "nf_url"]
```

And a list of dicts `urls_list`.

My goal is to clean my list of dicts `urls_list` by removing the dicts where none of the keys of the dict is a string of the list `fields`.
If at least one of the keys of the dict is `"website"`, `"product_url"`, `"catalog_url"`, `"dop_url"` or `"nf_url"`, the dict should be kept and not remove.

I saw many examples with any() or all() but I struggle to find something who fit my specific need.

Comment: No code, no specific question. No answer. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: It is unclear what *your need* is

Comment: Please add an example to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution with comprehension:

```py
fields = ["website", "product_url", "catalog_url", "dop_url", "nf_url"]
urls_list = [d for d in urls_list if any(k in d for k in fields)]
```

If the list needs to be edited in place, you can use the following syntax:

```py
urls_list[:] = # etc.
```